# Animation/.animate in Chrome sometimes goes "rises" instead of "falls"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm having an odd problem with Chrome; sometimes when refreshing, my divs (colored blocks) will rise instead of fall. I don't seem to have that problem on Pale Moon, but Chrome seems to run smoother than Pale Moon so I wanted to test it there. Any ideas? My code seems to be fine but I'm wondering if I need to put in some kind of "special code" to handle opening in Chrome, or something like that.

**HTML:**

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/script.js"></script>

<link href="css/hover/css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body id="home">

    <div class="container">
        <p>Website content here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="link" id="portfolio"></div>
        <div class="link" id="hamumu"></div>
        <div class="link" id="beep"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

body#home {
    background-color: green;
}

.link {
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#portfolio {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#hamumu {
    top: -260px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#beep {
    top: -295px;
    background-color: orange;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -150px;
}

.footer{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#hamumu", "#beep"];

$(document).ready(function() {

    //if on home page
    if ($("body#home").length > 0) {

       //run home function
       $(function() {
          homePage();
       });
});

//home page function
function homePage() {

    //place blocks
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        $(links[i]).css("left", i*"40");
    }

    //animate blocks falling
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        $(links[i]).animate({
            top: i*'-40'
        }, 1000*(Math.random()*(2-1)+1), 'easeOutBounce');
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your use of mathematical operators on strings under `homePage()`:

```
$(links[i].css("left", i*"40");
...
top: i*'-40'
```

In JavaScript, anything within a set of quotes (`'...'` or `"..."`) is considered a string object. You cannot perform mathematical operations on a string object without first converting it to some sort of numerical object. This means that certain math-exclusive operators like `*` and `/` will not do anything to strings, even if they're strings of numbers (JavaScript needs to be *told* the difference). It would be best to replace those two lines above with:

```
$(links[i].css("left", i*40);
...
top: -i*40
```

Also, there are a few syntax errors in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//if on home page
if ($("body#home").length > 0) {

   //run home function
   $(function() {
      homePage();
   });
});
```

Note that you do not close off the `if()` statement with a `}`. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //if on home page (not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve with this)
  if ($("body#home").length > 0) {
    homePage();
  }
});
```

Hope that helps and that the jQuery/JS learning goes smoothly for you!

Comment: @Terf please comment with any additional questions you have or mark this answer as correct if it has answered your initial question.